# Is "to blend in" the proper verb here?

Tags: word-usage

If I wanted to say that tigers can conceal themselves among plants, is it correct to say:

> *Tigers can blend in with plants*.

or should I use another verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [**blend in**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blend_1) is a phrasal verb:

> if someone or something blends in with people or objects, they match them or are similar, and you do not notice them

(from LDOCE)

It is usually used in a phrase *to blend in **with***, and very often so to describe camouflage in nature.

> *In a population of mice that live in the woods, for example, natural selection is likely to favor individuals that best blend in with the forest floor and are less likely to be spotted by predators.*

(College Biology, volume 2 of 3, Textbook Equity). There are more examples at [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22blend+in%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22blend+in+with%22&tbm=bks&start=10).

To me, it would sound a bit better if you said that the tiger blended in with the surrounding vegetation, but that might just be a personal preference.